# Are static methods a DI anti-pattern?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, mocking, static-methods

I am a Java developer who is *beginning* to grasp the full power of dependency injections, and it suddenly dawned on me that there's no way to inject a static method. So it got me thinking: **are static methods DI anti-patterns?**

More importantly: if I were to embrace dependency injection, does this mean I need to stop coding static methods? I ask because there is no way to mock them and inject mock statics during unit tests, which is a huge turn-off for me.

**Edit**: I know that a common way to "wrap" and inject an existing static method is like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void bar() { ... }
}

public interface FooWrapper {
    public void bar();
}

public class FooWrapperImpl implements FooWrapper {
    public void bar() {
        return Foo.bar();
    }
}
```

...but I'm not asking how to inject an existing static method...I'm asking if I should stop writing them altogether, if all my code (from this point forward) is going to embrace the notion of DI.

Also, I see a lot of similarly-related questions to this, but couldn't find an exact match that asked this same question. If you see that it is indeed a dupe of another question, please point it out to me and I will close this question myself (please don't just closevote it!).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Static methods are appropriate for things that don't have *associated state.*  Some factory methods,  "purely functional" methods like `Math.sin`, and the like are all perfectly acceptable static methods.  `java.lang.Math` and `java.util.Collections` have many fine examples of perfectly acceptable static methods.

Fortunately, these methods have no need for dependency injection, or to interact with such things; they're not unusually difficult to test.  They don't have dependencies that would need mocking or anything.

On the other hand, static state, or static methods with associated static state, are utterly evil.  That *is* an anti-pattern.

It frequently helps to define a method as being non-stateful (and therefore a legitimate static method) if, and only if, it always returns equivalent output on equivalent inputs.  This makes it clear that e.g. database queries and filesystem I/O makes methods stateful, because their outputs will vary depending on what's in the filesystem or the database.

Comment: So if I have a method called `fizz()` and in it I make a static call to a `Widget.buzz()` method, which hits a database and makes all sorts of changes to my local file system, then how do I test `fizz()` without invoking all the massive changes brought on by calling `Widget.buzz()`? My point is, I think I should stop writing static method altogether, so that I can then inject that correct `Widget` object (normal vs mock), and then control which "version" of `buzz()` fires at runtime. Thoughts?

Comment: `Widget.buzz()` has associated static state -- the database, and implicitly, the entire filesystem.  That's evil.  `fizz` could take a `Widget` argument, and you'd mock a `Widget` to test `fizz`.

Comment: Ahhh, I never thought about the database or the filesystem as being stateful. What criteria do you use to define "statefulness"? I think that's the root of my misunderstanding.

Comment: The entire point of a database is to be stateful, otherwise each time you turn on the computer you would have an empty database.  The same goes for the file system.

Comment: A method is not stateful if, and only if, it will always return equivalent output given equivalent arguments.  (Equivalent usually means `Object.equals`, but this varies depending on your exact use case.)  So your `Widget.buzz` method will return different results depending on the state of the database and the filesystem, even if it gets the same arguments -- so it's stateful.

Comment: -1 The question was about DI, not the philosophies of static methods in general. Btw,  Math has its evil twin StrictMath,  and it's reasonable to want to be able to swap one with the other. The answer is that non-trivial static methods are **not** compatible with DI,  regardless whether they use state.

Comment: NIO.2 moved file system operations out of instances of File into static Files. This contradicts your last paragraph.

Comment: what I find confusing about the 'static' world is that it makes ambiguous the concept that a type is like a 'stamp'.  i.e. some type Integer is a blueprint for creating integer numbers with associated operations.  When you start to add methods like Integer.add(int1, int2) it starts to behave like some Integer math library.  maybe this isn't a big deal but it makes the type more complex in my mind.

Comment: Took me a while to really understand DI pattern and static methods etc. Thanks for your answer which confirmed my understanding: use static methods only when no states are required

Answer (score 3):

Non-trivial static methods are **not** compatible with dependency injection. Simply make them instance methods of singletons.

Comment: You will then, of course, be calumnated by people who say Singleton is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score -1):

I'll rephrase your question as "How do I distinguish between when a java method should be static and when it shouldn't, when I am using dependency injection?"

In my opinion distinction should not be done purely based on whether is stateful or not, but rather whether you might want to mock the method in a test or not.
I am aware that newer BDD testing framworks like Mockito are fully capable of mocking static methods, but doing so comes at significant performance cost.