# Resolve type with IoC Container from within static Method

Tags: c#, java, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, static-methods

When using an IoC container without a static container instance (as this would result in a a service locator anti-pattern), how to resolve types from a static method?

Say, I have a method that reads an object `Document` from a file:

```
public class Document {
    // when used with IoC, the Logger gets injected via property injection
    public ILogger Logger { get; set; }
    /* ... */
    public static Document Read (string filePath)
    {
        // need to resolve an ILogger at this point?
        Logger.Info ("reading in {0}", filePath);

        /* ...read in document an return a document instance here ... */

    }
}
```

The Code is C# but same problem would apply to a Java project.

I know that a simple answer would be "don't use static method", but given the method is stateless i think it is one of the cases where static methods make sense.

Having a singleton IoC container would also help, but this is widely known to be an anti-pattern.

So, what is the way out of the problem?

Comment: Is it really "stateless" if it depends on the state of the injected implementation of your logger?

Comment: If we are already talking about best practices, I'm not sure you have made a convincing case at all that `Read()` should be a static method.

Comment: Well it is hard to reason that just due to the presence of a logging system, `static` methods should be avoided

Comment: @Dyna, just because you can't use IoC doesn't strictly mean you can't use static methods.  It just means that you can't inject the dependency by using IoC -- you'll have to set the property yourself some other way.  The need to use such a recourse is a disadvantage of static methods, but it's up to you to determine whether the tradeoffs merit it.

Comment: `static` methods should be avoided because they are rarely necessary. It's certainly not necessary in the case you presented (reading a file into a document object).

Comment: Ok, I see this is moving away from the original question to an "Are static methods an Anti-pattern" or "When to use static methods" disussion. This should maybe go into another question.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin, an enormous body of static methods in the BCL would like to argue otherwise.  (`System.IO.File`, `String.*`, `System.Linq.Enumerable.*`, etc.)

Comment: Should your logger be the static thing instead? It'd be easier to property-inject an `ILogger` once at startup into a static `Logger`, rather than having to do it all over your code. Also, isn't it a compile error to access an instance variable from a static method?!

Comment: @Dyna, the answer to your question is that it is not possible under IoC frameworks to inject static values.  The concept of static values violates the entire principle.  That being said, the solution to your problem -- if you choose to use static methods that depend on external state such as an arbitrary logging framework -- is to set the property yourself in the relevant bootstrapping code of your various endpoints.

Comment: @KirkWoll - unless OP is writing code for a document based API, I highly doubt `static` is the best design for this method.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin, don't disagree with your dimsissal in *this* case.  I was contesting what sounded to me like an almost blanket assertion on your part to avoid them everywhere.

Comment: @KirkWoll - maybe I'm just worn thin with looking at xxxxUtilities.cs files in every code base I touch. Obviously static methods have their place, or else language designers wouldn't allow them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, I can understand why this makes sense to write this function as static, the answer is simply that DI is not going well with static methods that have an associated state. Injected properties are a state of the object and static methods that have an associated state are considered to be an [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367610/are-static-methods-a-di-anti-pattern).

DI sometimes forces you to use pure (not anti) patterns.

If you insist on using static method in your case, I can suggest these to cover your options. All are not perfect.

1. Adding the injected objects as parameters to the function. 
   `Document.Read(logger, filePath)`.
   If you weren't using an IoC framework, the alternative was: 
   `new Document(logger).Read(filepath)`
   which is more or less, the same clumsy code for the caller.
2. Using a ServiceLocator as you stated.
3. Add a static initialization method to the class, and inject all of it's dependencies (as static properties). You would have to call this initialization in your application start.