# Mockito - how to mock a variable instantiated in a method?

Tags: java, rest, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following `Java` method:

```
public Appointment addAppointment(String client, Appointment appointment) {

        String esbUrl = new ESBUrlHelper().getEsbUrl();
        AppointmentClient appointmentClient = AppointmentClientFactory.getUnsecuredClient(esbUrl);
        
        if (appointment.getId() == null) {
            outputAppointment = appointmentClient.addAppointment(client, appointment);
        } 

        return outputAppointment;
    }
```

The method above makes a call to a third party `REST` client called `appointmentClient`.

The issue that I am having is that this is causing my test to fail.

How can I mock the `appointmentClient`object within my unit tests?

Currently my test looks as follows:

```
@Test
public void shouldAddAppointment() {

    // act
    Appointment appointment = appointmentService.addAppointment(CLIENT_STRING, appointmentMock)

    // assert
    assertNotNull(appointment);
}
```

But I get the following error at line `appointmentClient.addAppointment(client, appointment);`:

```
org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.ResteasyIOException: IOException
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
```

I want to mock something like as follows:

```
 Mockito.when(appointmentClient.addAppointment(client, appointment)).thenReturn(appointmentMock);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using PowerMockito for this.
First, you need to mock the static method call of `AppointmentClientFactory` class like below:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(AppointmentClientFactory.class); 
PowerMockito.when(AppointmentClientFactory,"getUnsecuredClient",esbUrl).thenReturn(appointmentClient);
```

And also, when you use PowerMockito for mocking static methods, add the `@PrepareForTest({AppointmentClientFactory.class})`  annotation to the test class.

Comment: Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367610/are-static-methods-a-di-anti-pattern. Using static methods that way and in this case is definitely anti-pattern. Yes, you could solve current problem this way, but you'll end up with ugly and hard-to-maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, the only way of mocking a call to `AppointmentClientFactory#getUnsecuredClient` would be using `PowerMock`, since the factory method is static. This is due to the hard coupling between your calling code `addAppointment` and the dependency here (i.e. the `AppointmentClientFactory`).

If I were you, I would avoid that as `PowerMock` is not the best way to do tests. Instead, what I would do, would be to inject the `AppointmentClientFactory` as a dependency thus allowing me to mock an instance of it during my tests.

This should be the best approach in twofold manner. Firstly, because you achieve less tightly coupled code and secondly because you do not need to use `PowerMock` for your unit-tests.

Comment: It is not that call that I want to mock, what I want to mock is appointmentClient.addAppointment - i.e. the REST call the client makes

Comment: Can you please show an example using Power mockito? thanks

Comment: Yes, it is indeed this one but in order to mock this call you do need a mocked instance (or a spied for that matter) of your REST client. With your current implementation you'll always invoke the `addAppointment` to a real REST client instance, which is destined to fail. That's why you need to mock the factory method in order to provide a mocked object.

Comment: can you please show an example of using Powermock in this case?

Comment: Using `PowerMock` should not be the way to go, especially since you have control over the code you are testing. I suggest refactoring your code to follow a DI pattern in order to allow for injecting a mocked dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible with Mockito. But your original problem is `static` method of `AppointmentClientFactory`. You definitely should change this method to the instance method (at least for better architecture) , for example:

```
 public class AppointmentClientFactory {

    public AppointmentClient getUnsecuredClient(String url) {
        return new AppointmentClient(); //your implementation
    }
 }
```

Then your AppointmentService will look like (or close to it):

```
public class AppointmentService {

    private final AppointmentClientFactory factory;

    public AppointmentService() {
        this(new AppointmentClientFactory());
    }

    public AppointmentService(AppointmentClientFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public Appointment addAppointment(String client, Appointment appointment) {
        String esbUrl = "";
        Appointment outputAppointment = null;
        AppointmentClient appointmentClient = new AppointmentClientFactory().getUnsecuredClient(esbUrl);
        if (appointment.getId() == null) {
            outputAppointment = appointmentClient.addAppointment(client, appointment);
        }
        return outputAppointment;
    }
}
```

And then you will could write test like:

```
public class AppointmentTest {

    private final String CLIENT_STRING = "";

    @Test
    public void shouldAddAppointment() {
        AppointmentClientFactory clientFactory = Mockito.mock(AppointmentClientFactory.class);
        AppointmentClient mockedClient = Mockito.mock(AppointmentClient.class);
        AppointmentService service = new AppointmentService(clientFactory);
        Appointment appointmentMock = new Appointment();
        when(clientFactory.getUnsecuredClient(any())).thenReturn(mockedClient);

        Appointment appointment = service.addAppointment(CLIENT_STRING, appointmentMock);

        assertNotNull(appointment);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply, I forgot to add in question that my AppointmentService class uses EJB as dependency injection.

Comment: You could inject your AppointmentClientFactory to the AppointmenService through constructor. And then you could use the constructor in your test, as I wrote above.